# Getting 'FormNotFoundError' in mechanize Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

I'm using beautiful soup and mechanize for web scraping the banking sites.

```
import re
import mechanize


br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
response = br.open("https://m.netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/")


br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['fldLoginUserId'] = "131325"
br.submit()
```

I need to enter the value in customer id text box, but I'm getting an exception every time. Can someone please help me out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    br.select_form(nr=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 669, in select_form
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching " + description)
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully. What does it say to you?

Comment: There is the form on that page, if we look at the HTML page, we can observe that. I tried my ways but I couldn't find any solution for that. Even it is not showing any form available in that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use selenium for this task.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./drivers/geckodriver')

driver.get('https://m.netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fldLoginUserId"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fldLoginUserId"]').send_keys('131325')


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="logintable"]//input[@type="submit"]').click()
```